Invalid wrapper type: google.protobuf.StringValue
I was using your demo project: https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-grpc-demos
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "My.Package";
option java_package = "com.my.package";

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

service MySvc {
  rpc GetBond(MyRequest) returns (MyResponse) {}
}

message MyRequest {
  string myValue = 1;
}

message MyResponse {
  bool success = 1;
  string message = 2;
  google.protobuf.StringValue messageStringValue = 3;
}

& reworked GrpcTest.java to:
import com.example.grpc.HelloRequest;
import com.example.grpc.HelloResponse;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit5.WireMockExtension;
import com.google.protobuf.StringValue;
import com.mine.My;
import com.mine.MySvcGrpc;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder;
import io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.RegisterExtension;
import org.wiremock.grpc.GrpcExtensionFactory;
import org.wiremock.grpc.dsl.WireMockGrpc;
import org.wiremock.grpc.dsl.WireMockGrpcService;
import wiremock.grpc.client.GreetingsClient;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.equalToJson;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.wiremock.grpc.dsl.WireMockGrpc.Status;
import static org.wiremock.grpc.dsl.WireMockGrpc.equalToMessage;
import static org.wiremock.grpc.dsl.WireMockGrpc.message;
import static org.wiremock.grpc.dsl.WireMockGrpc.method;

public class GrpcTest {

    WireMockGrpcService mockGreetingService;
    WireMockGrpcService mockRefDataService;
    ManagedChannel channel;
    GreetingsClient greetingsClient;

    @RegisterExtension
    public static WireMockExtension wm =
            WireMockExtension.newInstance()
                    .options(
                            wireMockConfig()
                                    .port(9090)
                                    .withRootDirectory("src/test/resources/wiremock")
                                    .extensions(new GrpcExtensionFactory())
                    )
                    .build();

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        var wiremock = new WireMock(wm.getPort());
        mockRefDataService =
                new WireMockGrpcService(wiremock, MySvcGrpc.SERVICE_NAME);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        channel.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    void dynamic_response_via_JSON() throws InterruptedException {
        mockRefDataService.stubFor(
                method("GetResponse")
                        .willReturn(WireMockGrpc.message(
                                My.MyResponse.newBuilder()
                                        .setSuccess(true)
                                        .setMessage("abc")
                                        .setMessageStringValue(StringValue.of("ASDAS"))
                        ))
        );
        System.out.println("START");
        sleep(30000);
    }

Using Postman I send a request to grpcMockServer & it ends up with error:
Exception in thread "grpc-default-executor-0" com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Invalid wrapper type: google.protobuf.StringValue
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeWrapper(JsonFormat.java:1616)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.access$2100(JsonFormat.java:1276)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl$2.merge(JsonFormat.java:1352)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1432)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.parseFieldValue(JsonFormat.java:1995)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeField(JsonFormat.java:1646)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeMessage(JsonFormat.java:1477)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1435)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1317)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$Parser.merge(JsonFormat.java:449)
    at org.wiremock.grpc.internal.JsonMessageUtils.lambda$toMessage$1(JsonMessageUtils.java:36)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Exceptions.uncheck(Exceptions.java:72)
    at org.wiremock.grpc.internal.JsonMessageUtils.toMessage(JsonMessageUtils.java:36)
    at org.wiremock.grpc.internal.UnaryServerCallHandler.lambda$invoke$0(UnaryServerCallHandler.java:92)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.AbstractRequestHandler.handle(AbstractRequestHandler.java:101)
    at org.wiremock.grpc.internal.UnaryServerCallHandler.invoke(UnaryServerCallHandler.java:60)
    at org.wiremock.grpc.internal.UnaryServerCallHandler.invoke(UnaryServerCallHandler.java:31)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:351)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:860)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

My dependencies on this testClass
java.io
java.lang
java.util
Gradle: com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.24.0
Gradle: io.grpc:grpc-api:1.59.0
Gradle: org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2
Gradle: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.10.0
Gradle: org.wiremock:wiremock-grpc-extension:0.3.0
Gradle: org.wiremock:wiremock:3.3.1


When I remove

.setMessageStringValue(StringValue.of("ASDAS"))

from willReturn() part there is no issue, I receive an expected response.

Issue also occurs with newer wiremock-grpc-extension(0.6.0): dependenties

java.io
java.lang
java.util
Gradle: com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.25.1
Gradle: io.grpc:grpc-api:1.63.0
Gradle: org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2
Gradle: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.10.0
Gradle: org.wiremock:wiremock-grpc-extension:0.6.0
Gradle: org.wiremock:wiremock:3.3.1


Building only WireMockGrpc.message() ends successfully, but seems off:

WireMockGrpc.message(
                                My.MyResponse.newBuilder()
                                        .setSuccess(true)
                                        .setMessage("abc")
                                        .setMessageStringValue(StringValue.of("ASDAS"))
                        ).build();

body content of result:
Body {content={
  "success": true,
  "message": "abc",
  "messageStringValue": "ASDAS" <- here value I think should be "value": {"ASDAS"}
}, binary=false, json=false}


changing setting value for strinvalue field to
.setMessageStringValue(StringValue.newBuilder().setValue("asda").build())`

did not helped



Please don't use image of text when it is trivial to copy and paste the text content into the question. Images may not outlive questions and inhibit our ability to reference their content.

You've added the com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java package but you do not show your imports for GrpcTest.java. Did you add import com.google.protobuf.StringValue;?

@DazWilkin yes, I've add
import com.google.protobuf.StringValue;
Updated description after your comments.

When using imported proto definitions you need to ensure you're including them when building the descriptor (.dsc) file.
In Gradle this is achieved via the following directive:
task.descriptorSetOptions.includeImports = true

The WireMock gRPC demos project has now been updated to reflect this:
https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-grpc-demos/blob/main/java/build.gradle#L74
